# Posting from multiple dynamically created HTML textarea elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, servlets, post

Given the following snippet:

```
 out.println("<form action=" + "./post" + " " + "method=" + "post" + " " + "id=" + "tweetForm" + ">");
        for (int i = 1; i <= twParser.currentTweetIndex; i++) {
            output = twParser.tweetArray[i] + newLine;
            out.println("<p>");
            out.println("<textarea" + " " + "name=text" + " " + "id=\"styled\"" + " " + "maxlength=140" + " " + "cols=" + "140" + " " + "rows=" + "1" + " " + "tag=" + "text_" + String.valueOf(i) + " " + "form=" + "tweetForm" + " " + "onfocus=\"setbg('#e5fff3');\" onblur=\"setbg('white')\"" + ">" + output + "</textarea>");
            out.println("<span class=label-style-countdown" + " " + "id=" + "chars" + String.valueOf(i) + ">" + String.valueOf(140 - twParser.tweetArray[i].length()) + "</span> characters remaining");
        out.println("<p>");
        }
        out.println("<input type=" + "submit" + " " + "name=" + "post" + " " + "value=" + "post" + " " + "style=\"float: left;\"" + "/>");
        out.println("<button type=\"reset\" value=\"Reset\">Reset</button>"
```

...that creates HTML multiple `textarea` elements and posts them to a servlet. But since all the textareas have the same name, only the contents of the first textarea are posted.

Is there a way to post them all?
Thanks

Comment: How about "name=text" + i.toString() + " " + "id=\"styled\"" + i.toString() + .. to make each textarea unique

Answer (score 3):

To have multiple inputs from same name you can use name array like

```
<textarea name="text[]">You text here</textarea>
```

which will post all the values having same name as an array.

PS: This can be done with any input types expect radio buttons

Answer (score 1):

On this line:

```
out.println("<textarea" + " " + "name=text" + " " ...
```

Append i to the name of the textarea, such that the names increase as `text1`, `text2` etc.

```
out.println("<textarea" + " " + "name=text" + i.toString() + " " ...
```

Perform the same loop on the server when receiving the POST request to receive from each textarea.

Comment: Thanks ,it seems to work.I `m thinking about pass "i" as a session parameter ? What do you think about it ?

Comment: i has different values for each iteration.  Do you mean the maximum i?  The upper bound?

Comment: Perhaps instead include it as part of the POST request?

Comment: Can you show me adding an individual variable to post request which is other than html element ? I test with session vars and it worked but having in post request is less complicated.

Comment: Just include a hidden field.  <input type="hidden" value="SOMEVALUE" name="imax">